# Python BeautifulSoup find span inside class

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to create a python script which finds a specific test inside a spam which comes from a class. Unfortunately i keep getting an empty response or "none".

It comes from a very specific page so ill paste a small bit of it which im trying to find:

```
<tbody>
<tr class="zone-dedicated-availability" data-actions="refUnavailable" data-dc="" data-ref="160sk5" data-availability="3600-">

<td class="show-on-ref-unavailable elapsed-time-since-last-delivery" colspan="5">
<span qtlid="47402">
                                        Last server delivered: today at 01:59.
                                    </span><br><a style="font-     size:14px;" href=".." qtlid="50602">Go for a VPS-CLOUD<br><span style="font-size:0.9em;" qtlid="50615">(from £5.99 excl.VAT)</span></a>
</td>
```

I am trying to get the "last server delivered" tekst from my script. I am still learning so would appreciate the help:

```
page = requests.get('...')
tree = page.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(tree)
table = soup.find('tbody', {'class': 'zone-dedicated-availability'})
print table
```

I am probably missing some at the find statement as this is where im stuck at now, tried a few different things but not sure how i can get a valid output like i need to.

Comment: There is no `tbody` tag in the document you provided.

Comment: I put it there, i said it in the text there but just added it now if that makes it more clear.

Comment: don't you have any `tr` tag before `td`?

Comment: I updated that with the tbody. Was just for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `class` attribute is in `tr` so you need to use this:

```
table = soup.find('tbody').find('tr', {'class': 'zone-dedicated-availability'})
```

or even better:

```
table = soup.find('tr', {'class': 'zone-dedicated-availability'})
```

You can also use a [CSS selector and the `select`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) method:

```
soup.select('tbody tr.zone-dedicated-availability')
```

To get the data you want is in the first "span" with `qtlid="47402"` thus:

```
In [19]: soup.find('tr', class_='zone-dedicated-availability').find('span', qtlid='47402').get_text(strip=True)
Out[19]: 'Last server delivered: today at 01:59.'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking for a table row with the class of "zone-dedicated-availability"?  It seems that you are currently searching for a table body with that class, and that it is unable to find it.